# TypeError: client.commands.get(...).execute is not a function (discord.js 12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I constantly keep receiving this error message and I do not know what the issue is. This error is present when I invoke the command `$eval input`.

I've tried several different codes, not that it might help but I keep receiving the same error, I've checked that the ID is correct.

**Error**: `TypeError: client.commands.get(…).execute is not a function`

- Eval file

````
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'eval',
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (message.author.id !== 'ID HERE') return;
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Evaluating...')
        const msg = await message.channel.send(embed);
        try {
            const data = eval(args.join(' ').replace(/```/g, ''));
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Output: ')
                .setDescription(await data)
            await msg.edit(embed)
            await msg.react('✅')
            await msg.react('❌')
            const filter = (reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name === '❌' || reaction.emoji.name === '✅') && (user.id === message.author.id);
            msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 })
                .then((collected) => {
                    collected.map((emoji) => {
                        switch (emoji._emoji.name) {
                            case '✅':
                                msg.reactions.removeAll();
                                break;
                            case '❌':
                                msg.delete()
                                break;
                        }
                    })
                })
        } catch (e) {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('An Error has occured')
            return await msg.edit(embed);

        }
    }
}
````

- Index file.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const translate = require("@k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const BOT_TOKEN = config.BOT_TOKEN;
const guildInvites = new Map();
const nodemon = require('nodemon')
const PREFIX = config.PREFIX
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

// Discord Presence

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
  client.user.setActivity("$help", { type: "PLAYING" }).catch(console.error);
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;
  try {
    client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});



// invite 

client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content === "$invites"){
      var user = message.author;

      message.guild.fetchInvites()
      .then

      (invites =>
          {
              const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === user.id);
              var userInviteCount = 0;
              for(var i=0; i < userInvites.length; i++)
              {
                  var invite = userInvites[i];
                  userInviteCount += invite['uses'];
              }
                   message.reply(`You have ${userInviteCount} invites and currently have ${userInvites.length} active invite links.`);
          }
      )
  }
});

  



client.login(BOT_TOKEN);
```

Appreciate the help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your command with

```
client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
```

However your eval-file has no exported member/function called `execute`. To fix it either change your command call to `client.commands.get(command).run(message, args);` or jus rename your run-method in the eval-file to `execute`. Also you should pass the correct parameters to the exported function when calling it. So you would basically end up with

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'eval',
    execute: async (message, args) =>
    ...
}
```

Both ways work. just remember that every command must have an exported function with the same name which can always be called by the **same name** in your index file.

Comment: I've just upvoted it as it solves the original issue but probably mention/fix the parameter mismatch too, as OP will have problems with that. `execute(message, args)` vs `execute: async (client, message, args)`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for the hint. I have completely overlooked that. (updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate both of your help I knew it was a simple error that I didn't catch, nonetheless I thank you again.